# Pressing enter key moves cursor to beginning of document in Chrome 43.0.2357.130 m

Tags: javascript, css, ckeditor

In my application, when i press enter key, line breaks but cursor shifts to the beginning of the document. Some of tricks i have appleid are :

```
config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_DIV;
```

OR

```
 config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
```

OR

```
config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_P;
```

But it makes no difference. Any hack?

Comment: Is there a live place where we can test this thing out?

Comment: I'm afraid it's not. I have made above changes in local config.js

Comment: What's the version of CKEditor?

Comment: Could you fork http://jsfiddle.net/oleq/zs61ym3v/ and create a sample? Does it still happen if you upgrade to 4.5.1?

Comment: I guess I have some local issues